# How to pass config file section names as argument in shell script

Tags: shell

I want to pass the config file section name as a argument or parameter to .sh file.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Below is my shell script and a conf file.

test.sh

`#!/bin/bash
    CONFIG=app.conf
    myuser=$(awk '/^\[user1\]/{f=1} f==1&&/^user/{print $3;exit}' "${CONFIG}")
    mypassword=$(awk '/^\[user2\]/{f=1} f==1&&/^password/{print $3;exit}' "${CONFIG}")
    echo $myuser
    echo $mypassword`

app.conf

```
[user1]
user = root
password = root123
[user2]
user = root2
password = root123
[user3]
user = root3
password = root12345
```

I want a script to be like when I run test.sh user2 It should print the variable values under the [user2] section.

Please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look

```
#!/bin/bash
    CONFIG=app.conf
    myuser=$(awk '/^\['$1'\]/{f=1} f==1&&/^user/{print $3;exit}' "${CONFIG}")
    mypassword=$(awk '/^\['$1'\]/{f=1} f==1&&/^password/{print $3;exit}' "${CONFIG}")
    echo $myuser
    echo $mypassword
```

pass user as an argument.

Comment: Hi agtabesh, 
I did this but now the values which I am getting are displayed in wrong way say for example 
app.conf has url=https://stackoverflow.com/post
and when I call it in the script as
url=$(awk '/^URL/{print $3}' "${CONFIG}")
echo $url/questions/52236027
It prints 
questions/52236027/https://stackoverflow.com/post

Can you please help?

Comment: This code work properly

`#!/bin/bash
        CONFIG=app.conf
        myuser=$(awk '/^\['$1'\]/{f=1} f==1&&/^user/{print $3;exit}' "${CONFIG}")
        mypassword=$(awk '/^\['$1'\]/{f=1} f==1&&/^password/{print $3;exit}' "${CONFIG}")
        url=$(awk '/^\['$1'\]/{f=1} f==1&&/^url/{print $3;exit}' "${CONFIG}")
        echo $myuser
        echo $mypassword
        echo $url/questions/52236027`